# Add money on balance using 2checkout

Tags: 2checkout

I have a website that charges some money for every service request (online calculator).

What 2checkout code should I add, so users can add money on balance?
I don't sell any products.

For example, on my site there is a user `test`. It has on balance $0.00.
When he uses calculator, he needs $1.5 in order to perform calculation.

How can he add that sum?

Second question. How to make minimal sum $10, so user can't add to balance less than $10?

Thank you.

Comment: What does your code currently do using 2checkout?

Comment: Didn't add any code, since don't know where to start from.

Comment: Then maybe you should start by learning something about 2checkout.